# PHP idn_to_ascii returns empty string for certain URLs

Tags: php, idn

I have successfully transformed thousands of urls with the `idn_to_ascii` function. But some (in my list about it is about 1%) are not - they look like normal url (not malformed), but i got empty string.

**Example:**

```
www.salonmeier.de/salon-meier-friseursalon-in-reichertshofen/datenschutz-und-impressum
```

PHP version is 7.0.12.

Comment: It is interesting, at my localhost PHP 5.6.11 it works perfectly. Maybe the issue is not dependent on php version, but on the version of "Internationalization Support". I have intl 1.1.0, locally.

Comment: After hours of testing i have realized that if the path part is shorter, then it works. For example `www.salonmeier.de/salon-meier-friseursalon-in-reichertshofen/datenschutz` is OK. The exact char count limit is 61, weird... It is for the path part only, the hostname can be longer, no matter.